# HttpWebRequest to different IP than the domain resolves to

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webrequest

Long story short an API I'm calling's different environments (dev/staging/uat/live) is set up by putting a host-record on the server so the live domain resolves to their other server in for the HTTP request.

The problem is that they've done this with so many different environments that we don't have enough servers to use the server-wide host files for it anymore (We've got some environments running off the same servers - luckily not dev and live though :P).

I'm wondering if there's a way to make WebRequest request to a domain but explicitly specify the IP of the server it should connect to? Or is there any way of doing this short of going all the way down to socket connections (Which I'd really prefer not to waste time/create bugs by trying to re-implementing the HTTP protocol).

PS: I've tried and we can't just get a new sub-domain for each environment.

Comment: Why can't you just specify the IP address in the request?

Comment: Have you tried using the IP address in the Uri and then setting the Host header?

Comment: Ragesh, the server will only answer if the Host header is correct (Their webserver is listening specifically for that domain name that doesn't resolve to it), so if I just use the IP address it doesn't respond correctly. Foole, I tried it but the host header on the HttpWebRequest won't let you set it (That is to say `request.Headers["Host"] = "www.example.com"` throws an exception)

Comment: If you like, I can post code for a custom HTTP request function.

Comment: Are you talking from sockets up? I don't really want to pick up maintaining a custom HTTP request function (I know enough about HTTP to do it, but the spec is huge and future features like HTTPS and all the edge-cases of the HTTP spec like redirects et al could be seriously annoying and time-consuming)...

Comment: This is a really old question, but [this answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26050285/52161) solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to spoof a HTTP host header is to set a proxy to the actual server you'd like the request sent to. Something like

```
request.Proxy = new WebProxy(string.Format("http://{0}/", hostAddress));
```

may well work.

Comment: Thanks... This was so long ago that I forget the actual workaround we finished with but I believe this was actually how we did it. I think webproxy takes an IP:port rather than http protocol though. I'll mark this right though so that if anyone else is looking they can find it (Forgot to put up answer when I found a solution originally).

Comment: No worries. Found this question on a drive-by search... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to control configuration values.

1. You have conditional compilation enabled in .NET, in which you can create your configuration sets and create directives that can use specific domain instead of changing its resolution strategy. For example, in debug, you can use x.com and in release mode you can use y.com, wherever you need to reference your url.
2. Web.config and app.config now supports changes as per the configuration selected, you can have web.debug.config and web.release.config and you can specify different url references here.

Comment: You appear to have completely misunderstood the question, changing the configuration will not help in any way because both webservers expect the same HOST header requested off them but it only resolves to one of them. So it's not x.com and y.com, they're both x.com.

Comment: I know, but when we deploy different web servers with different host header as well according to configuration that we need, anyway I think Jeremy's answer suites you thats good.