# Using System.Net.WebRequest with a known IP end point

Tags: c#, sockets, dns

I have a large collection of DNS names that have already been resolved to IP addresses. With this collection I need to download HTML from them. It's a very large list and I need to do it as efficiently as possible.

I'm using `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` to download HTML from the each domain. HttpWebRequest is repeating the DNS lookup, and this is adding to the connection time. I've run tests to see if sockets for those IPs on port 80 would connect faster and they do.

So I'd like to use HttpWebRequest with a known IP address, but I don't know how. All WebRequest factory methods require a URL.

Now I thought I could do something like this (where 1.2.3.4 is the IP)

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("http://1.2.3.4/");
req.Headers.Add(....); <-- add something here
```

I need to somehow add to the HTTP header what the target domain is, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
var ip = "93.184.216.119";
var host = "example.com";
var ipUri = new UriBuilder(Uri.UriSchemeHttp, ip).Uri;

var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(ipUri);
request.Host = host;

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    // do something with response
}
```

Comment: Yes. This works well. The Dns resolution offered by .net and all apis that rely on it sucks hard. Best avoided if you need to go fast.